# I'm Making Drop Down Menu, But It Shows Vertically Incorrectly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I found a video that explains how to create drop down menu, as the headlines should appear horizontally and sublines should appear vertically, with me the head & sub lines shows vertically! I checked the code many times, but I can't find where is the problem in the code!

I'm beginner to `HTML5` & `CSS`.

```css
#headlist ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: Roboto Light;
}

#headlist ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 1225px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #303030;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
}

#headlist ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

#headlist ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

#headlist ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

#headlist ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
```

```html
<div class="welcome">
  <div id="headlist">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#whos">Who We Are?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#keyp">Key People</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#divisions">Divisions</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#extl">ExtenzaLife</a></li>
          <li><a href="#ludic">Ludic Science</a></li>
          <li><a href="#flemon">Fleming-Monroe</a></li>
          <li><a href="#masslog">Massive Logistic</a></li>
          <li><a href="#masseng">Massive Energetic</a></li>
          <li><a href="#telcen">Teleportation Center</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#mdfound">Massive Dynamic Foundation</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p id="welto">WELCOME TO</p>
  <h1>  M A S S I V E<br>D Y N A M I C  </h1>
  <h2><span>“</span>What do we do? What don't we do!<span>"</span></h2>
</div>
```

the project content I inspired it from Fringe series.

Comment: what exactly is your question? Sorry but I can't quite clearly understand...

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're expecting to happen. What's a headline in your code? Maybe About, Divisions, Massive Dynamic Foundation? And the "sublines" are the links in the unordered list within those list items? Note that the selector `#headlist ul` is going to apply to all `ul` elements that are descendants of `#headlst`, at *any* depth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues with the original code...

Whenever you have a nested `ul li` structure like this (very common for menus), you must make sure that the CSS is specific enough to target the top level (main menu) and the child menus (dropdowns) separately. Your CSS was unintentionally targeting both, example:

```
#headlist ul li
```

This selector is targeting **ALL** the `li` elements in your menu when I believe you only wanted to target the top level items. To fix you can use the immediate child selector ">" like this:

```
#headlist > ul > li
```

This is targeting only `li` elements that are immediately inside of `ul` elements that are immediately inside of the `#headlist` element (the top menu items only).

Once you are clearly targeting the top level menu items and the drop down items with different CSS, you can achieve the desired layout more easily. I removed the float and styled the top level menu items like this:

```
#headlist > ul {
  display: flex;
}
#headlist > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

The top level menu becomes a flexbox container allowing the contained `li` elements to flow in a horizontal row. The `flex` rule on the `li` items allows them to grow to fill the available space.

The only other main change is I am using absolute positioning on the dropdowns which requires `position: relative` on the top level `li`s.

Not perfect but I hope this will help you get going in the right direction.

```css
#headlist ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: Roboto Light;
}

#headlist > ul {
  display: flex;
}
#headlist > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#headlist ul li {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #303030;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
}

#headlist ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

#headlist ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

#headlist > ul > li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 250px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

#headlist > ul > li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome">
  <div id="headlist">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#whos">Who We Are?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#keyp">Key People</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#divisions">Divisions</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#extl">ExtenzaLife</a></li>
          <li><a href="#ludic">Ludic Science</a></li>
          <li><a href="#flemon">Fleming-Monroe</a></li>
          <li><a href="#masslog">Massive Logistic</a></li>
          <li><a href="#masseng">Massive Energetic</a></li>
          <li><a href="#telcen">Teleportation Center</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#mdfound">Massive Dynamic Foundation</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p id="welto">WELCOME TO</p>
  <h1>  M A S S I V E<br>D Y N A M I C  </h1>
  <h2><span>“</span>What do we do? What don't we do!<span>"</span></h2>
</div>
```